# What is my study design

Tags: correlation, experiment-design, sample-size

I have two sample groups and I will not be manipulating the participants in any way so this is not an experimental design. 
However I wish to compare the results of the two samples (between subject group design) (one would be the control group in an experimental design and the other test group although I am not manipulating it). What makes the two groups independent from each other is that the group 1 is a normative sample while the other consists only of participants with a certain social (very important factor for this study) experience and same geographical background.

I will assess both samples for same questionnaires and cognitive tasks, but hope to find a relationship between a disorder and the 'test-group', compared to normative sample where there will be little or no relationship. I will also test for another variable that will show a relationship between both samples and the disorder.

Is it correct to call it a non-experimental correlational study? I have read that correlation study usually find correlation between two variables in one population. Thank you for any help clarifying this for me! Please ask me if I haven't mentioned any details necessary to determine the study design.

A correlational study requires minimum of 30 participants, if I have about 30 or 40 participants in each sample group, would that be ok?

Comment: what is the nature of  variables - datatype ? Which correlation analysis you have thought up. you are working on two groups. Have you gathered some data?

Comment: No Data collected yet. IVs: Refugee group & Normative group. DVs: Childhood trauma, schizotypal traits, social cogntion and working memory. I was thinking to do independent sample t-test, Mann-Whitney U-test and Chi-square test. However, as I have more than two variables in the hypothesis and I am working on two groups, I am not sure this is the most appropriate analysis.

Comment: between subject group design implies what ? on what basis,selection of subjects for test group. Refugee group Versus normative group. Are you having control group and test group for each of two category. State objectives of your study before you postulate design for study.Several types of correlation studies like intraclass correlation, eta- square are possible.

Comment: Aim to assess for trauma across all participants to replicate previous findings indicating strong relationship between childhood trauma and schizotypy. Hypothesise significantly stronger relationship between trauma and schizotypy and dysfunctional cognition among refugees due to the stressful life event of migration/war than normative sample.

Comment: Assuming that trauma (child) schizotypy can be quantified or scored with the help of standArd scale(s) or subscales or self-desighned questionnaire(s), the data can be generated for a number of subjects, Karl Pearson correlation coeffocient can be estimated. Alternatively, data may be translated in the form of levels of trauma experience and level of schizotype.Spearman rank correlation may be estimated.The significance test of computed  oorrelation will indicate strenghth of relationship between social (trauma experience) and schizotypy. A correlational study design is possible.

Comment: You have been of great help. Thank you very much! :)